# Yelp Api business search not working in react native using axios - returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, yelp-fusion-api

Having trouble getting the yelp api to work, it is supposed to search for businesses based on the set of term. I am using a async await function to GET the businesses/search object, then I am setting my params then updating state using setResults

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import SearchBar from "../components/SearchBar";
import yelp from "../api/yelp";

const SearchScreen = () => {
const [term, setTerm] = useState("");
const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

console.log(results);
console.log(term);

const searchApi = async () => {
 try {
   const response = await yelp.get("/search", {
     params: {
       limit: 50,
       term,
       location: "san jose",
     },
   });
   setResults(response.data.businesses);
 } catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
 }
};

return (
 <View style={styles.background}>
   <SearchBar term={term} onTermChange={setTerm} onTermSubmit={searchApi} />
   <Text>We have found {results.length} results </Text>
 </View>
);
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default SearchScreen;
```

Here is the SearchBar component

```
import React from "react";
import { View, TextInput, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const SearchBar = ({ term, onTermChange, onTermSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.backgroundStyle}>
      <Feather name="search" style={styles.iconStyle} />
      <TextInput
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
        style={styles.inputStyle}
        placeholder="Search"
        value={term}
        onChangeText={onTermChange}
        onEndEditing={onTermSubmit}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginHorizontal: 15,
    top: 15,
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginBottom: 20
  },
  inputStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  iconStyle: {
    fontSize: 35,
    alignSelf: "center",
    marginHorizontal: 15,
  },
});

export default SearchBar;
```

And here is where I used axios to set the baseUrl and header

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses",
  headers: {
    Authorization:
      "BearerZPzXkPFyF_mWgHVjj_a1QZqiFkktt_iXYcX8JED6Gp2i73aYJTsvfUSApIVh7w8B8CNYfwnvBKo50MZvR34dvO3Cm1tQxlFp_PnGgCFjce1h0I1UF3zcKHnr7eq8YnYx",
  },
});
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated I console.logged the results and term to make sure all my state is working and it is so it has to be some issue with how i'm getting the yelp api. My results always return an empty array.

**When Console logged**

the {result} just shows an empty array the starting state –

the {term} shows the state of whatever has been typed

**Expected result**

the {result} is supposed to show an arrays of objects matching "pasta" in the San Jose area and the number in the Text is supposed to show results.length

Comment: Do you get a 400 response? I noticed your Authorization token has a typo. It should have a space after "Bearer"

Comment: no 400 response and added the space after bearer and there was no change. In the console it just logs the {term} and the {result} Here is the git repository if you'd like to check it out. https://github.com/dabdavlin/ReactNativeRestaurantApp.git

Comment: the {result} just shows an empty array the starting state

Comment: the {term} shows the state of whatever has been typed

Comment: the {result} is supposed to show an arrays of objects matching "pasta" in the San Jose area and the number in the Text is supposed to show results.length

Answer (score 0):

I tried your repo. At first I got a `401` error because of no space in the auth token

```
sdk_gphone_x86_arm:
Error: "Request failed with status code 401" in
```

Then I got `400` for an invalid token

```
sdk_gphone_x86_arm:
start
sdk_gphone_x86_arm:
Error: "Request failed with status code 400" in
```

After corrected both, the app runs successfully, you can try it in
https://snack.expo.dev/@anthnoycc/searchscreen